# FFmpeg C API - seek through live stream

Tags: c, ffmpeg, rtmp, live-streaming, libavformat

I've opened a live RTMP stream using FFmpeg's C library, and I need to programmatically seek to the very end of the stream. This is after the stream is paused for an indeterminate amount of time. The closest I could get is the following:

```
av_seek_frame(pFormatCtx, -1, pFormatCtx->duration, 0);
avcodec_flush_buffers(pCodecCtx);
```

But the duration is 0 for live streams. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think if you can seek live stream as the media is not stored on the file so seek and pause will not work.